# EDit/save lists with less number of clicks

Tags: user-interface

For many of the pages in my site, i need to display the records in a table as a list. User/admin should have an option to edit, save,delete. In few pages they should be able to create records as well..Now my client is so conscious about the number of **clicks**. He wants everything to be done in **No** click or **less no.** of clicks

1. Display the list, on click of any
   record, an other page comes up to
   edit the details of this particular
   record. Now let us count the number
   of clicks, they are click on a
   record, enter the details and then
   click of button (Save and Return).
   So there are 2 clicks.
2. Display the list with radio buttons,
   by the side of the list there are 3
   buttons(Edit/save/Delete). Select
   the record to edit(set radiobutton),
   On click *Edit* the fields of that
   particular record are editable.
   *Save* button, saves the record. The no. of clicks are select the
   record(radio button click), click
   edit, click save. so there are 3
   clicks.

Please suggest any other alternative procedure with less no. of clicks..unfortunately in both the process they are able to edit only one record at a time. They would be happy if they can edit more than 1 record.

Thanks in advance! Deseperately waiting for suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the PHPMyAdmin interface?

Each row has a checkbox to select the row, and beneath the table you can select an ACTION to performed on the selected row(s).

Each row also has individual icons to edit/delete/... the row.

[image: http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/5288/phpmyadminrowstyle.png]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have never used it. http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php says that we can manage database, tables and relationship. But i need to manage table data but not the structure of it. can it be used for table data as well?

Comment: @lucky: Actually, I meant taking that UI as an example to develop your own, since it combines the best of both worlds: one-click modifications if you want to modify one row, but the possibility to modify multiple rows. But yeah, you **could use PHPMyAdmin to manage table data** - it's just more meant for technical people, not End-Users. Get a testserver running and try it out.